# Finding maximum values within a data set given restrictions

Tags: python

I have a task where I have been giving a set of data as follows

Station1.txt sample #different sets of data for different no. stations

```
Date       Temperature
19600101    46.1
19600102    46.7
19600103 99999.9 #99999 = not recorded
19600104    43.3
19600105    38.3
19600106    40.0
19600107    42.8
```

I am trying to create a function
`display_maxs(stations, dates, data, start_date, end_date)` which displays
a table of maximum temperatures for the given station/s and the given date
range. For example:

```
stations = load_stations('stations2.txt')
5
data = load_all_stations_data(stations)
dates = load_dates(stations)
display_maxs(stations, dates, data, '20021224','20021228' #these are date yyyy/mm/dd)
```

I have created functions for data

```
def load_all_stations_data(stations):
data = {}
file_list = ("Brisbane.txt", "Rockhampton.txt", "Cairns.txt",     "Melbourne.txt", "Birdsville.txt", "Charleville.txt") )
for file_name in file_list:
file = open(stations(), 'r')

station = file_name.split()[0]

data[station] = []
for line in file:
    values = line.strip().strip(' ')
    if len(values) == 2:
        data[station] = values[1]
file.close()

return data
```

functions for stations

```
def load_all_stations_data(stations):
stations = []
f = open(stations[0] + '.txt', 'r')
stations = []
for line in f:
    x = (line.split()[1])
    x = x.strip()
    temp.append(x)
f.close()

return stations
```

and functions for dates

```
def load_dates(stations):  

f = open(stations[0] + '.txt', 'r')

dates = []
for line in f:
    dates.append(line.split()[0])
f.close()
return dates
```

Now I just need help with creating the table which displays the max temp for any given date restrictions and calls the above functions with data, dates and station.

Comment: Is the ` #99999 = not recorded` actually in the file, or did you just add that for our benefit?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what those functions are supposed to do, particularly as two of them seem to have the same name. Also there are many errors in your code.

- `file = open(stations(), 'r')` here, you try to call `stations` as a function, but it seems to be a list.
- `station = file_name.split()[0]` the files names have no space, so this has no effect. Did you mean `split('.')`?
- `values = line.strip().strip(' ')` probably one of those `strip` should be `split`?
- `data[station] = values[1]` overwrites `data[station]` in each iteration. You probably wanted to `append` the value?
- `temp.append(x)` the variable `temp` is not defined; did you mean `stations`?

Also, instead of reading the dates and the values into two separate list, I suggest you create a list of tuples. This way you will only need a single function:

```
def get_data(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        data = []
        for line in f:
            try:
                date, value = line.split()
                data.append((int(date), float(value)))
            except:
                pass # pass on header, empty lines ,etc.
        return data
```

If this is not an option, you might create a list of tuples by zipping the lists of dates and values, i.e. `data = zip(dates, values)`. Then, you can use the `max` builtin function together with a list comprehension or generator expression for filtering the values between the dates and a special `key` function for sorting by the value.

```
def display_maxs(data, start_date, end_date):
    return max(((d, v) for (d, v) in data 
                if start_date <= d <= end_date and v < 99999),
               key=lambda x: x[1])

print display_maxs(get_data("Station1.txt"), 19600103, 19600106)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas`.  Reading in each text file is just a single function, with comment handling, missing data (99999.9) handling, and date handling.  The below code will read in the files from a sequence of file names `fnames`, with handling for comments and converting `9999.9` to "missing" value.  Then it will get the date from `start` to `stop`, and the sequence of station names (the file names minus the extensions), then get the maximum of each (in `maxdf`).

```
import pandas as pd
import os

def load_all_stations_data(stations):
    """Load the stations defined in the sequence of file names."""
    sers = []
    for fname in stations:
        ser = pd.read_csv(fname, sep='\s+', header=0, index_col=0,
                          comment='#', engine='python', parse_dates=True,
                          squeeze=True, na_values=['99999.9'])
        ser.name = os.path.splitext(fname)[0]
        sers.append(ser)
    return pd.concat(sers, axis=1)

def get_maxs(startdate, stopdate, stations):
    """Get the stations and date range given, then get the max for each"""
    return df.loc[start:stop, sites].max(skipna=True)
```

Usage of the second function would be like so:

```
maxdf = get_maxs(df, '20021224','20021228', ("Rockhampton", "Cairns"))
```

If the `#99999 = not recorded` comment is not actually in your files, you can get rid of the `engine='python'` and `comment='#'` arguments:

```
def load_all_stations_data(stations):
    """Load the stations defined in the sequence of file names."""
    sers = []
    for fname in stations:
        ser = pd.read_csv(fname, sep='\s+', header=0, index_col=0,
                          parse_dates=True, squeeze=True, 
                          na_values=['99999.9'])
        ser.name = os.path.splitext(fname)[0]
        sers.append(ser)
    return pd.concat(sers, axis=1)
```